# Can the RB Pi 4 Model B record two 4k streams from USB cameras simultaneously?

Tags: camera

I've never worked with Raspberry Pi before but I want to know more before I buy any components.

I'm planning to record a soccer field with two IMX317 cameras connected via USB to the Raspberry Pi 4B. Can the Raspberry Pi support that load for an extended period of time? Or is the 4k resolution too much to handle?

All I need it to do is save the recording to a microSD, post processing will be done on a high-end computer.

Comment: `never worked with RB before` what is an RB?

Answer (score 0):

4k stream, can the SD card handle that? I would propose a USB3 disk for video storage. And a 4k video stream is around 25 Mbps.

**Theoretical values:**

USB2 - 480Mbps (shared by all USB2 devices)

USB3 - 5Gbps (shared by all USB3 devices)

But there are limitations internally that for example limits USB3 to 4Gbps, that's the PCie - USB bridge, and perhaps there are some other culprits.